# Parse Multiline Text File into Multiple Variables

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, parsing, text-files

I'm a little stuck on a particular problem.  I'm working in .NET and need to parse a multiline text file into multiple variables.  So far, I've got it reading the first line, as far as I know.  Here's what the text file looks like:

```
1/10/2014 1,2,3
1 0 0
1 1 0
1 2 0
1 3 0
1 4 0
1 5 0
1 6 0
1 7 0
1 8 0
```

Here's what my code looks like for the first line - it's supposed to be pulling out the date (right now, it's not pulling out the date, it's assigning today) and the "1,2,3", then replacing the commas with spaces for "1 2 3".  For the rest, each number in each line should be its own variable, and that's where I'm stuck.  I only need to pick up the leading "1" for each subsequent line once as one variable (it will always be 0 or 1), and the second number in each is a tier number (those will always be 0-8), and the last numbers in each line, which are all "0" now, are all separate variables and will differ.

```
string filePath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FileName.txt"];
StreamReader reader = null;
FileStream fs = null;
fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
reader = new StreamReader(fs);
string line = null;
line = reader.ReadLine();
string[] lineInfo = line.Split(' ');
string NumbersTemp = lineInfo[1];
string numbers = NumbersTemp.Replace(","," ");
string date = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
```

As you can see, I haven't gotten very far with the variables and I'm not even sure if this is going to work correctly the way I have it so far.  It's not erroring out, but it's not complete.  Any help getting these variables laid out would be much appreciated.

Comment: Put ReadLine in a loop

Answer (score 3):

`StreamReader.ReadLine` reads one line. You are using it only once. Use a loop:

```
string date = DateTime.Today.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
string filePath = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["FileName.txt"];
using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using(var reader = new StreamReader(fs))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        string[] lineInfo = line.Split(' ');
        string NumbersTemp = lineInfo[1];
        string numbers = NumbersTemp.Replace(",", " ");
        // ...
    }
}
```

I'm also using the `using`-statement to ensure that all unmanaged resources are disposed property even in case of an error.

Comment: I understand the loop - does that mean that the first line is lineInfo[0], the next is lineInfo[1] and so forth, and the best way to grab the variables will be to get substrings of each line?

Comment: @user2697262: No `line.Split(' ')` split every line into chunks where each token is a "word" in a line (because you are splitting by spaces). So you can access each column/word via indexer of `lineInfo`. The loop justs iterates each line in the file. If you want to access it in the same way you need to load all into memory, for example by using `File.ReadAllLines(path)`. The returned array contains already all lines in the file.

Comment: I'm running into an issue plugging this in:

 CS1519: Invalid token 'using' in class, struct, or interface member declaration

Comment: @user2697262: Then you should tell us what code causes this. Maybe you want to ask a different question addressing that issue.

Comment: I have made quite a bit of progress.  The final error I'm getting is "File Error: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array."  It fails on lineInfo[1], and I don't understand why.

Comment: Indices are zero based in .NET. So if you want to access the first element you need lineInfo[0].

Comment: @user2697262: if you split a string you get an array which contains at least one element (even if the string is empty). But if the character/string you are splitting by is not contained in the string you get an array with one element. Then the `IndexOutOfRangeException` is thrown if you try to access the second element. This is what happened here. You can prevent it by first checking  `if(lineInfo.Length >= 2){// insert your code here}`.